# Overlapping 2DColliders preventing "OnMouse" methods

Tags: unity-game-engine, mouseevent, collision

I want to preface this by mentioning that I've already found and implemented a workaround to the below issue (shrinking the prefab colliders such that the buttons recognized them but the mouse didn't). I'm asking this question because, as a learning dev, it's in my best interest to figure out what exactly caused this bug in the first place and how to prevent it in the future.

As I said, I'm an amateur attempting to make my first non-tutorial project. The game is 2D, has two features relevant to my issue:

- a grid of BoxCollider2D objects, with a script to give them button-like functionality using the "OnMouse" suite of methods (ex. OnMouseEnter highlights, OnMouseUpAsButton triggers a click effect, etc.)
- a prefab consisting of two BoxCollider2D siblings, one with a collider slightly smaller than the buttons and one with a collider thrice the size of its sibling. These are spawned randomly in the grid by another object.

the problem is that the prefabs are conflicting with the intractability of the grid, causing buttons to only work when the mouse hovers over the sliver where they don't overlap the prefabs. Weirdly, this issue only effects *some* of the overlapping buttons, seemingly at random.

I've set the buttons on a higher layer than the prefabs, and set their sprites in a higher order just in case; neither of those did anything. I tried having the spawner destroy and respawn the grid, which didn't work because it disabled the scripts and colliders of all the child buttons for some reason. Interestingly, disabling and re-enabling the grid does reactivate some of the affected buttons, but again, it's random as to which are fixed and which aren't, and for some reason it only works once.

My current theory is that the prefabs are spawning "above" the buttons (in spite of this being a 2D project), such that the mouse interacts with the prefab and not the button. But this doesn't explain why not all overlapping buttons are affected. I would like to know what is causing this randomness, and if it's possible to have the button colliders take priority over the prefab colliders 100% of the time.

No code provided, since the actual contents of the "OnMouse" functions aren't relevant.

Comment: Can you clarify the problem + ideal outcome? From the above it reads like you have the prebabbed colliders overlapping the grid and preventing the grid from being interacted with, which you would expect. Maybe an illustration would help.

Comment: Right, it would *probably* help to clarify what I want answered on a question-asking site. Just edited it.

Comment: I've been experiencing overlapping colliders issues with MouseEvents as well, and as far as I could research on the internet there is no simple solution (as one might expect for a common issue like this) - only hacky workarounds such as the one you used, or avoiding overlapping colliders altogether (which may or may not be possible for you).